# How to find out if Zend Framework, Zend Server are installed on my machine?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-studio

I'm reading [Reference Guide::Create Your Project](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html). And it's written there:

> In order to create your project, you must first download and extract Zend Framework.
>
> After you have installed Zend Server, the Framework files may be found
> under **C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework** on
> Windows. The include_path will already be configured to include Zend
> Framework.

I didn't download Zend Framework or installed Zend Server (I have `XAMPP` installed with `Apache` and have `localhost` and can load php files in browser. I don't need any more server, I think). I just downloaded and instaled Zend Studio 9 and after the instalation I went this way:

```
File --> New --> Example...
```

and chose `Zend Framework Example Project` and named my project `"zend_project_example"`.

Then it was written that somthing was being instaled and it took quite a long time. Then I got this tree in the `PHP Explore` folder. And I even opened the **Controller code** from **Zend Framework Library**:

[image: http://www.ljplus.ru/img4/a/_/a_ya_vishe/pic.jpg]

So it seems I have ZF, but I don't have anything in:

`C:\Program Files\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework.`

In fact I only have **Zend Studio 9** folder threre: `C:\Program Files\Zend\Zend Studio 9.0.2.`

No any `\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework`

And in the Reference it is written:

> Open a terminal (in Windows, Start -> Run, and then use cmd). Navigate
> to a directory where you would like to start a project. Then, use the
> path to the appropriate script, and execute one of the following:
>
> **% zf create project quickstart**

I doesn't work for me. I can't do any steps farther in the [Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html). What should I have to solve and what should I have to do next to follow the Referance right way?

Thank you.

Comment: So, the Zend is in your include_path what You have to do is setup the cli tool to be available from the command line : http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html and there are many tutorials on the web how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend Studio is just an IDE - an environment which is supposed to make developer's life easier. You need a server to run your projects on localhost. You quoted

> After you have installed Zend Server,

and you wrote

> I didn't download Zend Framework or installed Zend Server,

You can't expect the tutprail to work if you don't do what it says.

Comment: I have XAMPP installed with Apache. I have localhost and can load php files in browser. Everything works fine. I'm changing DW for Zend Studio and want to know its features, reading now the Reference and met some problems. The Reference is not the same as real work. And I don't now farther steps

Comment: Probably you have to configure zend studio to use apache instead of zend server - I've never used it and I can't help you with this. But if you can open php files on browser, then there is no problem - start a new, clean project from zend studio and open your newly created php files in browser by typing `localhost/your_file.php`

Answer (score 0):

http://www.zend.com/en/downloads/

this is to download link for zend server and which would you like preferred you choose and you save manually and double click on setup file easy to install on your system